# How to Create C# Documentation Using SandCastle

Tags: c#, xml

I am using Sand Castle with Visual Studio 2010 to create documentation for my C# code. 
I am able to create documentation using xml comments with C# code. But It shows all in documentation like classes, methods, interfaces etc. But I don't want to generate private classes  documentation. I tried to find out but I didn't find.

So, Any-one can help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Anyone help me how to create C#_ You can't create C#. But if you want help, show your work first. Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Are you using visual studio as IDE?

Comment: yes, I am using Visual studio 2010.

Comment: SandCastle in combination with the SandCastle Help File Builder works perfect! Sounds like you didn't really dive deep into the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everything to work you have to add the documentation help to be associated with each of the `class`, `method`, `properties` etc. For adding XML documentation to any of them just type `///` at the previous line of every function, class etc it will generate all the tags and then you can fill the information about them.

For example,

```
///
public Class1()
```

and you will see XML help section generated automatically in Visual Studio as,

```
 /// <summary>
 ///              //You can add description here....
 /// </summary>
 public Class1()
 {
```

After generating these tags you can follow the instructions posted at [Documentation Generation](http://gusclass.com/blog/2013/02/25/creating-html-documentation-in-c-using-visual-studio-and-sandcastle/)